# Django superuser creation no response

Tags: django, postgresql

I have been trying to create a superuser but it eventually gives me no response and just sits idle after I fill out the password.

```
(venv) [root@ubuntu:~/folder/pfg]$ python3 manage.py createsuperuser
Exception in importing from settings_local, continuing without
No module named 'pfg.settings_local'
System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
content.Item.category_measures: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
content.Item.vocab_items: (fields.W340) null has no effect on ManyToManyField.
Username (leave blank to use 'root'): django
Email address: cewehuj@email-server.info
Password:
Password (again):
```

The exception occured even during `python3 manage.py migrate`, but all the checks after that went OK, so I'm hoping the exception is not that serious.

Comment: can you post the exception?

Comment: @prashant it is there in the snippet I posted. I mean, that is all there is.

Comment: have you tried using django admin ui?

Comment: no. will it let me create a superuser and outcome won't be different?

Comment: You might have issues with your folders.  It says it can't load the module `pfg.settings_local`  which means it's trying to load a file `~/folder/pfg/pfg/settings_local.py`  Is that where your settings file is?